# show that $f$ is constant over the level sets of $\phi$ if $G = \nabla \phi $ and $fG$ is conservative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

As the title suggests, i'm having trouble to show this. By premise, $G : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, $\phi: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ twice continously differentiable and $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$. The problem suggests using the following identity: $\nabla \times (fG) = \nabla f \times G \ + f(\nabla \times G)$.

By replacing $G = \nabla \phi$, using that $fG$ is conservative, and that since $\phi \in C^2 \implies \nabla \times (\nabla \phi) = 0$, it can be concluded that $\nabla f \times \nabla \phi = 0$. Now, how can I use this fact to prove that $f$ is constant over the level sets of $\phi$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement in your title is not quite correct. You need the level sets of $\phi$ to be connected in order for this to be true. For example, consider $f(x)=x$ and $\phi(x)=x^2$ in $\Bbb R$. Here $G=2x\vec i$ and $fG = 2x^2\vec i$ is certainly conservative. (You can easily create similar examples in higher dimensions.)

Directly, apply the chain rule. Suppose $\alpha(t)$ is any curve contained in a level set of $\phi$ and passing through $p$. Then $\phi(\alpha(t))$ is a constant function of $t$. By the chain rule, $0=\dfrac d{dt} \phi(\alpha(t)) = \nabla \phi(\alpha(t))\cdot\alpha'(t)$. Since $\nabla f$ is parallel to $\nabla\phi$ at each point, it follows that $\dfrac d{dt} f(\alpha(t)) = \nabla f(\alpha(t))\cdot\alpha'(t) = 0$ as well. This tells us that $f$ is constant along $\alpha(t)$ and hence along the connected component of the level surface passing through $p$.